# Describe the decrease in potential energy if two forces are acting on it one conservative which is greater than other applied by us in opposite dirn

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, gravity, newtonian-gravity, work

So imagine this situation.
An object is experiencing two forces, one due to gravity in downward direction and other applied by us in upward direction such that our force is less than   gravitational force.
So the object will accelerate downward and its potential energy will decrease.
Will the change in potential energy equals to negative of the work done by gravity?
And If so then how, isn't it should be less than that because of our force, but then the change in potential energy will be negative of the work done by resultant force.
Thanks if you answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the change in potential energy equals to negative of the work
> done by gravity?

Yes.

> And If so then how, isn't it should be less than that because of our
> force, but then the change in potential energy will be negative of the
> work done by resultant force.

No.

Gravity is a conservative force, meaning the work it does, and the resulting change in gravitational potential energy, depends only on the initial and final position of the object. So it is independent of the force you apply to the object. In other words, the difference between the work done by gravity and the work done by you between the initial and final positions has no effect on the change in potential energy.

On the other hand, the net work done by gravity and determines the change in kinetic energy of the object between its initial and final position. If gravity does more positive work on the object than the negative work done by you, there will be an increase in kinetic energy between the initial and final positions, in addition to a loss of gravitational potential energy,

In your example, since the force you apply is less than the force of gravity, there will be an increase in kinetic energy between the intial and final positions..

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that actually helped a lot.